# Python Selenium access Cookie-Consent

Tags: python, html, selenium, cookies

I am trying to scrape this Webpage with Python and selenium, but when i try to click the **"OK" Button for cookies consent**, i can't find it: [Picture that shows the Consent Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIrCM.jpg)

https://www.immonet.de/

This works: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#usercentrics-root")`

But when i **try to select the OK Button** by `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#uc-center-container > footer > div > div > div > button.sc-gsDJrp.cXArZu")` then i get an **Error**:

`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#uc-center-container > footer > div > div > div > button.sc-gsDJrp.cXArZu"}`

I already tried to access this I-frame `driver.switch_to.frame("uc-cross-domain-bridge")` but then i did not get any resulting elements i could work with.

**How do i access the cookie-consent-dialog**

EDIT: With help from @Curtis i found that this was hidden under a shadow dom. Got it working with:

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

shadow_section = expand_shadow_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#usercentrics-root"))
shadow_section.find_element_by_css_selector("#uc-center-container > footer > div > div > div > button.sc-gsDJrp.cXArZu").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the cookie button is under a shadow-root.  Check out how to get those elements here: https://medium.com/rate-engineering/a-guide-to-working-with-shadow-dom-using-selenium-b124992559f

Comment: Awesome, thats the keyword i needed to get along with my google searches!

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='OK']").click()
```

Comment: This still does not work actually: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='OK']"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)